# Load more content when user scrolls "near" bottom of page?

Tags: jquery

I use this to detect scroll to the bottom of page. But how do I detect a distance from the bottom of the page?

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() ) {
 .. my ajax here
}
```

I mean i want the function to execute when he is 100px or 200px from the bottom, and not in the very bottom of page. How would I change this?

Also: is it possible, to instead catch if the scroll is at the last of a specific element (say my big CONTAINER) which shows the loaded content.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ["Infinite scroll"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059526/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin) is a feature that has been thoroughly addressed elsewhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var nearToBottom = 100;

if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > 
    $(document).height() - nearToBottom) { 
 .. my ajax here 
}
```

or to scroll to the bottom of .CONTAINER

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= 
    $('.CONTAINER').offset().top + $('.CONTAINER').height() ) { 
 .. my ajax here 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This will help you.

```
<script>
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
        alert("End Of The Page");
    }
 });
</script>
```

Go through this link for whole article and details how it works.

[load more content when browser scroll to end of page in jquery](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/05/browser-scroll-to-end-of-page-in-jquery.html)