# Infinite scroll without jquery?

Tags: javascript, scroll, native

I can't find any plugin that makes infinite scroll functional without jQuery. Is there something like this?

https://github.com/alexblack/infinite-scroll - doesn't work:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [infinite-scroll jquery plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059526/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this iscroll, it works on mobile device as well !

http://iscrolljs.com/

Comment: Nice! Tnank you! https://github.com/alexblack/infinite-scroll also works well. I have <body> `display: flex;` and my `document.addEventListener("scroll"...);` don't work. That was my problem

Comment: @VaganovAndrey did you open the console to see if there is any error being thrown? I mostly develop my javascript using chrome and its awesome "developer tools" you can find when pressing F12, go to the "Console" tab.

Comment: of course:):) http://iscrolljs.com/ - there is no errors.